# Алгоритм вычисления определителя: ошибка подхода

Tags: java, массивы

Здравствуйте! Повторно выкладываю алгоритм вычисления определителя матрицы размером 3*3

```
public class Opredelitel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Minor Min = new Minor();
        Double[] Crew = new Double[13];
        Double[][] MatrixNet = new Double[3][3];
        MatrixNet[0][0] = 0.1;
        MatrixNet[0][1] = 0.5;
        MatrixNet[0][2] = 1.5;

        MatrixNet[1][0] = 1.1;
        MatrixNet[1][1] = 1.5;
        MatrixNet[1][2] = 1.0;

        MatrixNet[2][0] = 2.1;
        MatrixNet[2][1] = 2.5;
        MatrixNet[2][2] = 0.5;

        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < MatrixNet.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MatrixNet.length; j++)
                    if ((i != k) & (j != 0)) {
                        int t = 0;
                        Crew[t] = MatrixNet[i][j];

                        double m = Min.Chek(MatrixNet[0][0], MatrixNet[1]
                                [0], MatrixNet[2][0], Crew);
                        System.out.print(m);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class Minor {
    public double m;
    public double Chek(double MatrixNet1, double MatrixNet2, double MatrixNet3,
                       Double[] Crew) {
        for (int i=0; i<=13;i++)
            m = double MatrixNet1*(Crew [0]*Crew [3]-Crew [1]*Crew [2])-double
        MatrixNet2*(Crew [4]*Crew [7]+Crew [5]*Crew [6])-double MatrixNet3*(Crew
                [8]*Crew [11]-Crew [9]*Crew [10]);
        return m;
    }
}
```

В вызывающем методе 3-мя циклами отбираются элементы трех алгебраических дополнений, для элементов в 3-х строках. То есть всего 12 элементов.

На следующем этапе я хотел эти 12 элементов MatrixNet[i][j] записать в новый, уже одномерный массив Crew[t], затем передать этот новый массив в качестве аргумента в метод Minor, в котором уже вычисляется определитель, как сумма произведений соответствующих элементов на их алгебраические дополнения. Соответствующие элементы передаю также в качестве аргументов.

НО: вместо значения определителя (одна цифра) выдает последовательность 12 элементов 3-х алгебраических дополнений. То есть, я так понимаю, в метод Minor передается не массив Crew, а последовательно каждый элемент массива Crew и он же возвращается в m. Что не соответствует поставленной задаче

Comment: Укажите в метках к вопросу язык программирования (я конечно подозреваю, что это C#, но могу ошибаться).

Comment: Извините, java. Для меня последние полгода другого языка "не существует", поэтому на автомате не поставил:-)

Comment: @Andrey1981spb у вас в первой итерации Crew имеет заполененный только 0 позицию. а в методе Chek вы обращаетесь к остальным позициям. код точно рабочий?

Comment: @Andrey1981spb также детерминанат равняется сумме произведений. а у вас переменная `m` принимает только поседное значение итерации цикла

Comment: @Andrey1981spb как я понимаю. вы хотите реализовать алгоритм для матрицы любой размерности? так как для матрицы 3х3 можно готовую формулу написать

Comment: мне кажется легче было бы для каждого минора рекурсивно вызывать функцию определителья. если 2на 2, то по формуле, иначе разложить и вызвать рекурсивно

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий про первую итерацию (и за все остальные). Я понял ошибку! Я ведь копирую элементы массива MatrixNet[i][j] в Crew[t] но до этого, как справедливо указали, инициализирую только 0 позицию. Поэтому Crew принимает только первый элемент и его же передает!  Получается, надо циклом проинициализировать все элементы t. Только, как я понимаю, это должен быть  цикл, НЕ вложенный в предыдущий...